# SAM build fails because Maven install fails with "The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda, serverless-application-model

I have an issue where I am trying to get `mvn install` to work so that my `sam build` works with local invocation using Docker, but it keeps failing due to the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project my-project: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]
```

There are many different iterations of problems and solutions regarding "The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact" on StackOverflow, but none of them seem to resolve my issue.

For example, I can do a `mvn jar:jar install:install` and that works correctly, but I can't specify goals like that in the SAM build, so that isn't a proper solution -- I need `mvn install` to work.  I have tried many variations of deleting the .m2 folder, which does nothing.  I can also change the version of the maven-install-plugin to no avail.  I can specify the file in the maven-install-plugin and if the path is correct, it doesn't see it, but if it is incorrect, it says it doesn't exist.

Nothing seems to solve the issue, so I need to find a real solution.

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jersey.version>2.30.1</jersey.version>
        <jackson.version>2.10.2</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <!-- excluding redundant javax.inject dependency -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.925</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--START LOGGING DEPENDENCIES-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--END LOGGING DEPENDENCIES-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudfront</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.927</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>shaded-jar</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <transformers>
                                        <transformer implementation="com.github.edwgiz.maven_shade_plugin.log4j2_cache_transformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer" />
                                    </transformers>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                                <version>2.13.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>assembly-zip</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- don't build a jar, we'll use the classes dir -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-jar</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- select and copy only runtime dependencies to a temporary lib folder -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>zip-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src${file.separator}assembly${file.separator}bin.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <attach>false</attach>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

And here is my bin.xml:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>lambda-package</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <!-- copy runtime dependencies with some exclusions -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}lib</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <!-- copy all classes -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>${file.separator}</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 6):

After much searching and many trial and errors, I finally figured out how to resolve this and figured I would share for those that are suffering through this like I was.  There are two methods:

1. You can remove the following plugin:

```xml
                    <!-- don't build a jar, we'll use the classes dir -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-jar</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

While this makes it function correctly, it also produces a jar file, which may not be desirable, especially in the case of a Lambda (unnecessarily increases its size).

1. (Preferred solution)  Add the maven-install-plugin with a skip configuration:

```xml
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

This solution both solves the problem and prevents you needing to create a jar file.  This allowed my SAM build to work as a result of Maven functioning correctly.